# Is it true that $\gcd(p+1,pk)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving, gcd-and-lcm

Let $p$ be a prime. Consider the statement $\gcd(p+1,pk)=1$. The statement does not seem to be true for all $k$. In particular, take $k=3,p=2,\gcd(2+1,2(3))=3>1$. So is this statement true if $\gcd\nmid k$?

Comment: You have hit an important restriction.  If $d$ is common divisor of $p+1$ and $k$ then it will be a common divisor of $p+1$ and $pk$ so $\gcd(p+1, pk) \ne 1$.  But can there be any other common divisor?  Maybe a better statement is $\gcd(p+1, pk) = \gcd(p+1,k)$.  Do you think *that* is true?.  ... or as we must have $p+1$ and $k$ reltative prime, is that enough?  Is "If $\gcd(p+1, k) =1$ then $\gcd(p+1, pk)$" a reasonable statement?  Do you think you can explore that.

Comment: what does /| mean?

Comment: If prime $a$ divides $pk$, but does not divide $k$, then it must divide $p$.  This implies that $a=p$.  This then implies that $a$ is relatively prime to $(p+1)$.

Comment: @user71207 $\not |$ is the symbol for does not divide.

Comment: I've edited that symbol to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: gcd$(p+1,pk)=$ gcd$(p+1,k)$.

To see this, let $q$ be a prime and $r$ a positive integer such that $q^r$ divides $(p+1)$ and $q^r$ divides $pk$. Then as $p$ does not divide $p+1$ it follows that $q \not =p$ so $q$ does not divide $p$ and so $q^r$ must divide $k$. So if $q^r$ divides $(p+1)$ and $q^r$ divides $pk$ then $q^r$ must divide both $p+1$ and $k$.